# want to parallelize a nested for loop using multithreading in java

Tags: java, multithreading, parallel-processing, nested-loops

I want to parallelize a nested for loop using executor service or using any other method in java. I want to create some fixed number of threads so that CPU is not completely acquired by threads. Each thread here is doing some independent work.First thread should execute *j = 0, 20, 30, 40, ...*  Second thread should execute *j = 1, 21, 31, 41, ...* Each thread should execute parallel. Here is what I want to do,

```
ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(NoOfThreads);
  for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    for(int j=0; j < 50000000; j++) {
      //some independent work
      //parallelize this work
    ...
```

Here is what I did

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(20);
  for (int j=0; j < 50000000; j++) {
    executorService.execute(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        //do some work
        //send data to some api
      }});
  }
  executorService.shutdown();
  while (!executorService.isTerminated()) {
    System.out.print("");
  }
}
```

I want to make sure that this is the right implementation of what I wanted to do. Please let me know how can I improve my code.

Comment: I suggest using parallel streams and let it handle your problem. It may work, it may not work, I'm not sure, but I would test it.

Comment: @Shadov I think this is not really good advise. The simple truth is: there are no detours in life. Especially when talking about using "parallel" abstractions in programming. One has to **understand** what you are doing. Just throwing "parallel streams" at somebody who doesn't have much clue about using parallel things in general won't help much. He is already overburdened using executors and tasks. What good would come out of pulling up parallel streams?!

Answer (score 0):

Well, there two obvious problem here:

```
 while (!executorService.isTerminated()) {
   System.out.print("");
 }
```

will mean that your **main** thread that is calling this code will do **hot** waiting. You should do a Thread.sleep() call here; to avoid burning zillions of CPU cycles for absolutely no reason.

But doesn't matter too much; because your code here

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(20);
```

creates 100 * 20 threads; working on 50000000 tasks you intend to push into them. Maybe I am wrong; but I have a certain gut feeling that will push most systems beyond their limit.

Leading to: structurally, this is not a good approach. Creating that service; and adding tasks; and the task content itself are all different things.

In that sense:

- you want to create **one** executor service (using a number of threads that somehow resembles the capabilities of the underlying hardware)
- you want to push a **smaller** number of tasks into that

Meaning: when you have to work on 1 million elements, you do not create 1 million tasks. You maybe create 1000 tasks; and each one works 1000 elements.

Answer (score 0):

Your code allocates 50000000 Runnable objects, which will be slow.
Instead, each worker thread should run a loop that fetches the next "j" value to process.  Use AtomicInteger to make sure each "j" value is processed exactly once.

Here is some outline code:

```
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

public class ParallelLoop {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            final int n = 50000000;
            final AtomicInteger atomicJ = new AtomicInteger();

            int nThread = 20;
            ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(nThread);
            for (int t = 0; t < nThread; t++) {
                Runnable r = new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        while (true) {
                            int j = atomicJ.getAndIncrement();
                            if (j >= n)
                                return;
                            // Process J ....
                        }
                    }
                };
                es.submit(r);
            }
            es.shutdown();
            es.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.DAYS);
            System.out.println("====");
        }
    }

}
```